# GWT Java - Server Side "for loop" not working

Tags: java, for-loop, server-side

I am reading in a file in which each row has a column no, row number, detail. The file is sorted on column then row. I want to place the detail in a csv file in the correct row and column. So I am testing for change in row number and then add in line breaks ("\n").

The issue is that the System.out.println on each side of the for loop is being displayed in the log; however, the loop its self is not triggered (i.e., the line break is not added and the System.out.println is not appearing in the log.

The code is:

```
System.out.println("New row - " + Integer.parseInt(report.getReportDetailRow())+ " greater than current row - " + currentRow);
            currentCol = 0;
            //Add line breaks
            int j = Integer.parseInt(report.getReportDetailRow());
            for(int i = currentRow; i > j; i++){
                System.out.println("Append line break");
                fileContent.append("\n");
            }
            System.out.println("After append");
            currentRow = Integer.parseInt(report.getReportDetailRow());
            if (currentCol == Integer.parseInt(report.getReportDetailColumn())){
                fileContent.append(report.getReportDetailDetails() + ",");
                currentCol++;
            }else{
                //Add columns
                for(int i = currentCol; i == Integer.parseInt(report.getReportDetailColumn()); i++){
                    fileContent.append(",");
                }
                fileContent.append(report.getReportDetailDetails() + ",");
                currentCol = Integer.parseInt(report.getReportDetailColumn());
            }
```

Please note that I have use "i > j" instead of "i == j" to try to force a result.

Comment: What are `i` and `j` usually? If you had `i == j`, it would execute at most once, did you mean `i < j` or something?

Comment: Hi Iluvatar, i < j is the answer. Please post as an answer and I will accept and vote up. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your statement for iterating through the rows, you have

```
for(int i = currentRow; i > j; i++)
```

If `j` is the number of current rows, then you need to change your condition to `i < j` to go through them all.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = currentRow; i > j; i++) {
    System.out.println("Append line break");
    fileContent.append("\n");
}
```

The loop above would either result in an infinite loop or never get triggered(your case)

- Infinite if `i` is already greater than `j`. It would never terminate with `i++` for every iteration
- Never execute if `i` is less than `j`, since the condition states `i>j`.

You might want to change the conditional statement inside the loop to correct this to either `i==j` or `i<j`

```
for(int i = currentRow; i == j; i++) // in which case replacing this with an `if(i==j)` would do the needful
```

or

```
for(int i = currentRow; i < j; i++) // to iterare from initial i upto j
```